# GCC: __attribute__((malloc))

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, malloc

Quoting from [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (emphasis mine):

> The *malloc* attribute is used to tell the compiler that a function may
>   be treated as if any non-NULL pointer it returns cannot alias any
>   other pointer valid when the function returns **and that the memory has
>   undefined content**. This often improves optimization. Standard
>   functions with this property include `malloc` and `calloc`. `realloc`-like
>   functions do not have this property as the memory pointed to does not
>   have undefined content.

I have the following code:

```
struct buffer {
    size_t alloc;  // Allocated memory in bytes
    size_t size;   // Actual data size in bytes
    char data[];   // Flexible array member
};


#define ARRAY_SIZE <initial_value>

buffer *buffer_new(void) __attribute__((malloc))
{
    struct buffer *ret;

    ret = malloc(sizeof(struct buffer) + ARRAY_SIZE);
    if (!ret)
        fatal(E_OUT_OF_MEMORY);

    ret->alloc = ARRAY_SIZE;
    ret->size = 0;

    return ret;
}
```

Now I'm a bit puzzled here: though I didn't initialize the `data` member, I still set the `alloc` and `size` fields to their respective values. Can I still consider this allocated segment to be of "undefined content" and use the *malloc* attribute?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of the attribute. For example, `calloc` returns memory with well-defined content.

Comment: @KerrekSB since the attribute explicitly states the content is undefined, and since `calloc`'s memory is very plainly defined, I think I must be misunderstanding something too... could you expand on this?

Comment: I think the attribute is for assisting with aliasing analysis. The compiler can assume that the returned memory does *not* contain, say, the pointer to an existing object.

Comment: @Kerrek Seams reasonable. I think the manual's wording is quite unfortunate.

Comment: Probably a good question to some gcc developers list (to improve that document)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is safe to mark your `buffer_new` function with `__attribute__((malloc))`, because the block it returns contains no pointers.

The latest GCC documentation clarifies the meaning of `__attribute__((malloc))`: the block returned by a function so marked must not contain any *pointers to other objects*. The intention is to help the compiler estimate which pointers might possibly point into the same object: the attribute tells GCC it needn't worry that the object your function returns might include pointers to something else it's tracking.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that having pointers in a memory area allocated in a function marked with the attribute is a bad thing. I had a Heisenbug in a double linked list code that I searched for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from a code review in the Ubuntu forum and yes the documentation needs to be improved 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.7/+bug/1123588